# symfony 1.4: adding defailt value to a model

Tags: php, database, model, symfony1

I'd like to add some default values to a model when I'm creating a new entry (like a timestamp)

I'm sure there are more than one way of doing this, I'm curious what the different ways are, but mostly what the standard way of doing this is.

Thanks

---edit---

solution:

for the timestamp the default would be

```
default: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `default` key in your schema, like this:

```
felhasznalok_kezelese:  { type: boolean, default: false }
```

Works for all field types.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll definitely 'felhasznalok' this